# In R Getting object ' ' not found with ggstatsplot::ggpiestats

Tags: r

I am executing the code below in R to build a pie chart:

```
>   ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(data = df,
+                                  main = dname,
+                                  counts = sp_max,
+                                  title = "Top 10 Obs",
+                                  legend.title = "Obs",
+                                  results.subtitle = FALSE,
+                                  palette = "RdBu") +
+     theme_void()
```

I am getting object ' ' not found (note that the object name is empty).

```
Error: object '' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
object '' not found
Backtrace:
  1. ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(...)
 11. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 12. tidyselect:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()  
<error/rlang_error>
object '' not found
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(...)
  2. | +-base::nlevels(...)
  3. | | \-base::levels(x)
  4. | \-`%>%`(...)
  5. +-dplyr::pull(...)
  6. +-dplyr:::pull.data.frame(...)
  7. | \-tidyselect::vars_pull(names(.data), !!enquo(var))
  8. |   +-tidyselect:::instrument_base_errors(...)
  9. |   | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 10. |   \-rlang::eval_tidy(enquo(var), set_names(seq_along(vars), vars))
 11. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 12.   \-tidyselect:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
<error/simpleError>
object '' not found
```

My packages versions are:

```
> packageVersion("ggstatsplot")
[1] '0.7.2'
> packageVersion("tidyselect")
[1] '1.1.0'
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] '1.1.3'
> packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] '1.3.0'
```

My dataframe definition is:

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dname      : chr  "OBS1" "OBS2" "OBS3" "OBS4" ...
 $ sp_max     : int  18845 16397 16205 14605 14039 12931 12761 12300 11811 11486
```

Have anyone experienced this before?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like you should be specifying a `x=` parameter so it knows what column to use from your data. There is no parameter named `main=` at least according to the documentation online.

Comment: Please don't add tags that aren't relevant to your question. You aren't directly using the `dplyr` or `tidyselect` packages and this isn't specific to the RStudio IDE.

Comment: I am sorry, not sure what do you mean by this.  If calls for certain packages / functions are referenced in the error stack why it should not be specified in tags?  Also, to your previous comment, "main" does exist in the documentation.

Comment: MrFlick, thank you for the first comment, replacing main by x worked, thank you.  The puzzling thing in all this: I run the same exact code above on a similar R installation but with ggstatsplot::ggpiestats 0.6.1 (all other packages are the same version) and it works without any issues.

Comment: The version on CRAN which you have installed (0.7.2) does not use `main=`. I can see that used to be the name in older versions of the package. I'm not sure if you installed from github previously or not. If you bring up the `?ggpiestats` help page, do you still see `main` listed? If so, somehow you have a bad version of the package. Try reinstalling from CRAN: `install.packages("ggstatsplot")`

Comment: You are spot on, the upgrade from 0.6.1 to 0.7.2 is the culprit. Thank you for your help! most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrFlick comments above helped nailing down the issue - Thanks. Changing "main" to "x" in the ggstatsplot::ggpiestats call fixed the problem.